# YouTube Video Upload "Authentication Error" in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, youtube-api

I am working on an iOS application which includes video sharing on YouTube. I have created YouTube secret key and Client ID. I have also enabled API from Google API manager.

While I am trying to upload the video on YouTube I am getting pop up with error message 
                   "Authentication Error" 
              The operation couldn't be completed.
              (com.google.HTTPStatus error 401.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, The issue is with the 'OAuth 2.0 client ID' generated, Earlier I have generated OAuth 2.0 client IDs with type 'iOS' but it was not working. Now I have generated OAuth 2.0 client IDs with type 'Others' and this time I am able to share the video to YouTube from my app.